# Tap to restart app and go full screen - when changing device orientation

Tags: android, orientation, android-tiramisu

we recently upgraded to android 13, and realised that when the device get's turned to landscape mode, we see a reload icon on the bottom right of the screen, and a message above it that says:

> Tap to restart app and go full screen

[image]

Once we hit that button, the app actually turns to landscape, and everything works fine.

Here's a vid:

[image: rotation vid]

And here's my manifest activity config:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    android:launchMode="singleTask" 
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:exported="true"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
>
```

What is this (maybe a new android feature?), and how can I remove that button, and make sure the app goes to landscape without user input?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It was the `android:screenOrientation` setting in our manifest.

Removing that stopped the problem.
I wonder why that wasn't a problem in the past, but it is now.